# Confusion on a term related to connection and holonomy

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, holonomy

This question is simply some of my confusions about a specific term.

Let $E\to X$ be a trivial complex vector bundle. When one says let $\nabla^E$ be a connection on $E\to X$ with trivial holonomy (not restricted holonomy), does it mean $\nabla^E$ is induced by a trivial connection on the trivial bundle $X\times\mathbb{C}^k\to X$ via a trivialization $\varphi:E\to X\times\mathbb{C}^k$, where $k$ is the rank of $E\to X$?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: @BenMcKay Thank you very much.